# Display formulas by formatting/cell settings

Tags: formula, libreoffice-calc

How is it possible to display a formula in Libreoffice by a simple change of the formatting or the cell settings of the desired cells?

I'd like to have a table which displays the results and another which displays the formulas next to each other. (at the same time)

The solution Options->LibreofficeCalc->View->Formula doesn't work as the whole document is affected. Also in the print-preview it falls back to the results. (I wish to print it later)

The plugin [Display Formula and Result (Value) simultaneously](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/display-formula-and-value-simultaneously) does display them both at the same time but I'm not happy as it seems to work under limited conditions only (Some working formulas are just displayed as *###* and if I use it on the whole table it formats cell by cell without the ability to undo it. Having a 5x5 table will cause 25 *Ctrl+Z* if it's not working as supposed)

Comment: Can you give an example of a case where the add-on does not work correctly?

Comment: @JimK - I had used only very simple formulas `=E1*A3` or so. But in some cases the formula seems to be messed up if one of the cells is a merged cell.

Comment: I tried using it on merged cells, and it does unmerge them but other than that, it seems to work correctly.  If there is something else going on, try to find out when exactly the problem occurs and give a reproducible example.

Comment: @JimK - I went through some tests and your answer is perfectly right: The _###_ appeared because the cells were too narrow.
But two other issues came up: 1) The cell `=c7/b3` was not converted to the simultaneous output by the plugin. Nothing happened. 2) Can it be the plugin messes with the printer-output? We set up three tables (7x8 cells) next to each other. One with the calculations, one using `=FORMULA(cell)` and the last one with the plugin (right to the first table). The print-preview just had one single cell on it and the print too. Removing the plugin solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the formula `=FORMULA(cell)` to display the formula used in `cell`

Answer (score 2):

If you specifically require formatting, then the `Display Formula and Result (Value) simultaneously` add-on seems to work as desired.

Formulas are displayed as ### if the cells are too small.  When this occurs, resize the columns and the full formula will appear.

As to undoing quickly, there are a number of methods:

- Select the cell range and go to Format -> Clear Direct Formatting.
- A table of 5x5 can be quickly undone by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> for about two seconds.
- Format -> Conditional Formatting, and hold down shift to select multiple.  Press Remove.
- Format -> Styles and Formatting, and hold down shift to select multiple styles.  Then delete them.
- Reset the whole sheet by running the `CFClear` macro from https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=62169.
- Save the file first and then reload if it is not what you wanted.

To me, the biggest downside of the add-on is that it can potentially double the file size, and it clutters up conditional formatting and cell styles.  But if formatting some cells as a formula is a priority, then it seems like a good solution.

Comment: Related to undoing: I was talking about the plugin. If you use it on several selected cells and you're unsatisfied with the result every single cell has to be undone separately. Apparently the plugin works sequentially